# Android phone as Wi-Fi access point

Tags: android, wifi

I am developing an application which requires android phone to be configured as a wireless access point.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe it is a feature of Android 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

It's a feature of Froyo (Android 2.2) (Settings >> Wireless >> Tethering & portable hotspot).

Comment: Hi Mike, I couldn't find Tethering and portable hotspot option in 2.2 emulator...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible on an unrooted phone.

If your target is rooted phones you can check out [android-wifi-tether](http://code.google.com/p/android-wifi-tether/).